# Prevent the selectedItem from reappearing as another option in the Semantic-UI dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, semantic-ui

I'm using Semantic-UI framework to provide multi-select dropdown functionality. 
When the user clicks on submit I'm doing certain checks, retaining the selected items and repopulating the dropdown.

HTML

```
<div class="ui dropdown search selection multiple fluid" id="ddValues">
   <input type="hidden" name="selectedId">
   <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
   <div class="default text">Select values</div>
   <div class="menu"></div>
</div>
```

excerpts from JS

```
$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown('clear'); //Clear dropdown
for (bussinesLogic) {
    var option = $('<div/>', {
        'class': 'item',
        'data-value':id,
        text: name
    });
    if(loggedIn)
       option.append("<i class='user icon pull-left'></i>")
    $('#ddValues .menu').append(option); // **Add to dropdown**
    $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown('set selected', id);
}
```

The problem is selectedItem is appearing in the dropdown again as another option. Although clicking on it from dropdown doesn't show it as another new selectedItem in dropdown.

If I skip the "Add to dropdown" then it messes up my workflow. 
How do I prevent the selectedItem from reappearing as another option in the dropdown.

Thanks